# How to download huge numbers of child objects as CSV in Silverstripe CMS?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm working on a Silverstripe project which has a Batch > Item relationship.

A Batch can have up to 50,000 Items.

This is how the relationship is set-out:

```
class Item extends DataObject {

  private static $has_one = array(
      'Batch' => 'Batch'
  );

class Batch extends DataObject {

  private static $has_many = array(
      'Items' => 'Item'
  );

class BatchAdmin extends ModelAdmin {

  private static $managed_models = array(
      'Batch',
      'Item'
  );
```

This natively gives the CMS user the ability to download **all** Items as a CSV from the CMS.

I'm trying to work out two things:

1. How do I make sure that large downloads don't fail due to lack of memory/ script time etc?
2. How do I add an "Export to CSV" button to each Batch which downloads only the Items in that batch as a CSV?

Comment: you are not alone :)
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/2431

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add an *Export to CSV* button to `Batch` which exports the related `Items` we add a `GridFieldExportButton` to the Batch CMSFields:

```php
class Batch extends DataObject {

    private static $has_many = array(
        'Items' => 'Item'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        $itemsConfig = GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create();
        $itemsConfig->addComponent(new GridFieldExportButton());

        $itemsField = new GridField(
            'Items',
            'Items',
            $this->Items(),
            $itemsConfig
        ); 

        $fields = new FieldList(
            $itemsField
        );

        return $fields;
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. I've added this line to prevent script time out:     ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600);